# What format does Windows make screenshots in?

Tags: windows, screenshot

So here I am in quite a pickle.

If you make a screenshot in Windows 7, it is presented to you in .png format. The question is, does Windows first create a bitmap screenshot and then without your explicit consent convert it to .png? Or is it made in .png from the start?

Question no. 2:

Why it uses 24-bit format for the image? And is it 1-byte per colour or do those 24 bits include some kind of transparency?

Comment: How are you taking the screenshot? Are you using winapi? Why do you think it is converting it to png? The 24 bit is 1 byte per color. No transparency is included in a screenshot.

Comment: Every raster image is normally created/loaded as some kind of bitmap in memory, the first question does not make sense...

Comment: How are you "making the screenshot" you're referring to (WinAPI, the keyboard PrintScreen, GDI+, or something else)? The answer to #1 depends entirely on how "Windows" is making the screenshot. The answer to #2 can be found via Google - the 24-bit PNG format is publicly documented and readily available.

Comment: Using the native Windows function, using the PrtScn button.

@MatteoItalia I see, you are right about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: It makes .png right away, and even if it didn't I don't see what difference would it make. Format .png is a raster format(bitmap) itself, very similar to .bmp, the only difference is that is can be compressed, but that doesn't erase any usable data in it.

2: Each color takes 1 byte = 8 bits, one byte for each channel,  R(ed), G(reen) and B(lue). That sums up into 3 x 8 = 24 bits(not bytes). You can also add one more channel for transparency, usually called Alpha, which would be the 4th byte and then one pixel will have 32 bits.

Comment: Do you have a source for this info?